# Why is the index not being used?

Tags: mysql, innodb, b-tree

I have a table (say table `t`) with an index on `col_a` that is unique.

Now the index on `col_a` is used in these 2 following cases -

- `SELECT * from t WHERE(col_a,col_b) IN((x,y),(p,q));` - query_1
- `SELECT * from t WHERE(col_a = x and col_b = y) OR (col_a = p and col_b = q);` - query_2

But not when I query like so -

- `SELECT * from t WHERE(col_b,col_a) IN((y,x),(q,p));` - query_3

In fact, I don't find any difference in query style of query_1 and query_2 and query_3. Aren't they functionally the same for MySQL? I was expecting the index to be used here.

Comment: Why test col_b if col_a sufficies?.  (Well, it is needed as a secondary check.)

Answer (score 0):

For most of MySQL's existence, "row constructors" were poorly optimized.  Only recently have some obvious use cases been optimized.  I guess your case was missed.

Comment: Could you point me to relevant doc for this that states so? The mysql version is 5.7.x

Comment: Let's see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`   In 5.7.3 "EXPLAIN output for applicable queries will change from full table or index scan to range scan. Changes are also visible by checking the values of the Handler_read_first, Handler_read_key, and Handler_read_next status variables."

Comment: Handler counts:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts

Comment: Not sure how "Handler counts" answers this?

Comment: @Dumb_Pegasus - It can be useful for comparing two query formulations -- to see which one touches fewer rows.

Answer (score 0):

Because the writing style of (col_1, col_b) uses tuple, which follow the leftmost prefix principle, col_ The index of a can be used, col_ The index of b cannot be used

Comment: They are functionally the same. Your answer still doesn't explain why would the query optimizer choose to not use the index.

Comment: Left most prefix principle